# Assign Post variables to Session variables in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, session, post

I'm writing a code to process a form which consists of multiple pages of collecting information from the user. It's in ASP.NET w/ C#.
So I thought instead of using Post to pass between pages, I'd use Session to store them.

My flow is that each page gets the Post values from its previous page and instantly assign them into corresponding Session variables under the same identifiers.
Is there a simple way to handle it instead of manually assign each variable?

Some codes will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not that this wouldn't work, but it's a code smell and you should totally avoid it.

Comment: @PaolodelMundo so, I really should do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a (POCO) class, set your values on the class, then place that class in session.  Then on the next page get that class from session and modify as needed...and do that for all your pages.

(EDIT)SIMPLE EXAMPLE:

```
// store this class in a file in your app_code folder called something like MyClass.cs
public class MyClass
{
   public string SomeStringValue;
   public int SomeIntValue;
   public List<SomeOtherClass> MyClassCollection = new List<SomeOtherClass>();
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public string OtherStringValue;
}

// At the beginning of your form, on your first page, instance this class
MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass();

// Then, when you collect the data on the page, set the values in the class
oMyClass.SomeStringValue = "derp";

// Then, store it on session in that page
Session["oMyClass"] = oMyClass;

// Then, on the next page, get the object from session
MyClass oMyClass = (MyClass)Session["oMyclass"];

// Then, set the next value in your object
oMyClass.SomeIntValue = -1;

// Then, place it back in session on that page, and then keep chuggin through your workflow.

// Now, I didn't show you how to use MyClassCollection that is in the MyClass object, but it would be simple for you to store a class from each page in that collection like so
SomeOtherClass oSomeOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
oSomeOtherClass.OtherStringValue = "herp";
oMyclass.MyClassCollection.Add(oSomeOtherClass);

// Then you can place that collection in session
```

Comment: Any sample code, please? I was a PHP programmer, now getting started to ASP.Net. Thanks so much!

Comment: added a very simple example - this is similar to the session object in php: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php